# How to show progress when loading initrd?

Tags: boot, initrd, grub-legacy, progress-information

I have a complete root fs built into initrd, so it's almost 500MB. It takes a while to load to memory and during this time, the screen has no indication of the progress. I would like to know if there is a way show progress as initrd loaded to memory? (Such as PXE boot loading kernel will have '.' per 1MB.) I'm using GRUB Legacy, and I can patch the source if needed.

Comment: The initrd is loaded by the bootloader, not by the kernel. What bootloader are you using?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. The purpose of `initrd` is to mount the `rootfs` at a pre-boot stage and the `initrd` is a compressed `gzip` file that is decompressed in ram. I would create the `rootfs` as compressed `squashfs` image which is loaded from `initrd` by a small perl script where you easily can implement a progress bar.

Comment: @Gilles Good point! I'm using grub legacy, I don't know if it's possible now.

Comment: @bersch, squashfs won't work, because I'm loading entire debian to the Clio archive and it needs to be rw for normal operations.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about grub legacy, but in grub 2 (which I'm using) I've added 'insmod progress'. That gives me indication and progress.